# Dart Invalid constant value in builder: (context, child) when using flutter screenutil

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub

Am completely new to flutter and as matter of fact this is my first bite in using it and I really can't figure out why dart is yelling at me when using `ScreenUtilInit` from flutter_screenutil package, with `invalid constant value` error coming from `builder: (context, child)`. I have searched everywhere on the web and read the pub documentation and i still couldn't find tune how to appease these choking bug.

Here is the code snippets

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const ScreenUtilInit(
      useInheritedMediaQuery: true,
      designSize: Size(375, 812),
      minTextAdapt: true,
      splitScreenMode: true,
      // The Invalid constant value is coming from the next line
      builder: (context, child){
        return const GetMaterialApp(
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          title: "JobMon",
          theme: ThemeData(
            scaffoldBackgroundColor: kLight,
            iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: kDark),
            primaryColor: Colors.grey,
          ),
          home: defaultHome,
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

I will really appreciate some help here cause i don't really know what am doing wrong here.

Comment: Does removing `const` help? The error means “you’re saying this object is a static, never changing one, but it uses variable data so it cannot be constant”

Comment: Wow! Thankssssssssssss. I appreciate you big time. removing const really did work.

Comment: Thank you so much @Randal for the eye pointer video about GetX. It really did help, as i now know better what am getting into, as a beginner with hunger for production ready application...

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `const` keyword from `GetMaterialApp` widget.

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const ScreenUtilInit(
      useInheritedMediaQuery: true,
      designSize: Size(375, 812),
      minTextAdapt: true,
      splitScreenMode: true,
      //Remove the const keyword
      builder: (context, child){
        return GetMaterialApp(
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          title: "JobMon",
          theme: ThemeData(
            scaffoldBackgroundColor: kLight,
            iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: kDark),
            primaryColor: Colors.grey,
          ),
          home: defaultHome,
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I did remove `const` keyword from `GetMaterialApp` widget, and is working fine now. Thank you so much, i appreciate you! @Arijeet

Comment: Please accept the answer if you found this useful.

Answer (score 0):

Because of `builder` function is typically expected to create new `widgets` dynamically based on runtime data, so it cannot be treated as `const`, so `ScreenUtilInit` cannot be `const` in this case.

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ScreenUtilInit( // const removed
      useInheritedMediaQuery: true,
      designSize: Size(375, 812),
      minTextAdapt: true,
      splitScreenMode: true,
      builder: (context, child){
        return const GetMaterialApp(
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          title: "JobMon",
          theme: ThemeData(
            scaffoldBackgroundColor: kLight,
            iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: kDark),
            primaryColor: Colors.grey,
          ),
          home: defaultHome,
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Though, I had created `constants.dart` where i added the `const kDark = Color(0xFF000000);`, `const kLight = Color(0xFFFFFFFF);`, etc.

Comment: @SamuelOshio response is edited